# Normal implies characterstic

Tags: group-theory

We know that  if in a group G , HcharG then H is normal in G
But converse is not true.
converse is true when (|H|,|G/H|)=1.
Then how we show this.
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an order, and some of us don't like being ordered to do things. Please rewrite in a friendlier fashion. Also, If you don't know how to prove the converse is true under that condition, how do you know that the converse is true under that condition?

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be normal in $G$. Then we have a characteristic subgroup $C := \prod_{\alpha \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)} \alpha(H)$ with $H \leq C \leq G$. By considering the possible orders of $C$ we can conclude $H = C$.